# Tag cleanup - permissions tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I noticed this today and wasn't sure if a Meta question was needed or not.  Not sure on the procedure/care for consolidating tags such as this.

[image: permissions tags]

It would seem to me that we could combine `permissions`, `file-permissions`, `user-permissions`, `directory-permissions`, and `permission` into one (possibly even throwing database-permissions into it as well since there are only 16).

Again, not sure which ones should/shouldn't be combined together or all of them, but seems like the explanation under `permissions` stating:

> Questions related to permissions or access rights for operating
>   systems, filesystems, servers, or network devices

pretty much covers all of these in one.

Answer (score 6):

[directory-permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/directory-permissions) and [file-permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-permissions) can get combined.

[permission](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/permission) and [permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/permissions)

[database-permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/database-permissions) questions had nothing to do with DB permissions....

---

Not so sure about combining [permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/permissions) and [file-permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-permissions)

Seems like overlap, but they have a fair amount of individual use.

Comment: I concur.  No real difference between directory and file perms, just different philosophy.

Comment: "Permissions" is a pretty ambiguous tag -- probably worth an audit to see if they always mean file/directory permissions or someone is incorrectly using it for (e.g.) SELinux or BSD-MAC "permissions"

Comment: Permissions and file-permissions are indeed different.

Comment: They *should* be different tags, but that's about 1/4 overlap. So obviously they're conflated in some/many questions, but not others... probably something that has to be fixed manually (if at all)